# request dependent bean injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Scenario: Configuration in my spring-boot application is dependent on the environment, let us say Development, Test and Production.These configurations would usually load based on the deployment environment.

But, my requirement is such that, the request I get in the rest controller will have the environment and this may change for each and every request. Now what is the best way to use the environment based bean configs based on my request.

Solutions I tried:

1. My initial option was to refresh the active profiles when I get a request to the controller, but this requires reloading of the configurations.
2. **Another option was to pre-load all the beans for all the environments. But, there is one parameter that I get in the request that needs to be used to load one of the bean.**

Answer (score 0):

Usually the environment is static and by the time spring begins to start its already resolved. For example, if you're in dev environment - the application starts with all beans/configuration defined for this environment.

I also don't see how logically possible that the same java process serves / deployed in all environments simultaneously, maybe you should give concrete examples of code that you have at least at the level of interfaces.

Spring is designed in a way (at least its a conventional usage) that once beans are create (Application Context is started) they serve all the requests, and you never reload them if they're in Scope Singleton.

Bean is created out of bean definition (a special kind of internal spring representation of data required for bean creation, stuff like name, scope, etc.), and this again is created during the spring initialization process, so even if you recreate bean Each time (scope prototype), I don't believe it will serve your needs.

So Basically what you're asking for is against spring design if you wish.

I believe besides aforementioned prototype scope that unlikely will help here, the most sane answer would be refactoring of the part of the application that has this behavior.

Here is an example of a solution :

```
  enum Environment {
     DEV,
     TEST,
     PROD  
  }

  interface SomeStrategyOfEnvironmentDependentCode {
      void invoke();
  }

  @Service
  public class MyRefactoredService {

      private Map<Environment, SomeStrategyOfEnvironmentDependentCode> envStrategies;


      public void foo(Environment env) {
              envStrategies.get().invoke();
      }
  }
```

Now, Usually environment should not be a part of the logic, so that the application should not give any assumption on which environment does it run. In other words if tomorrow you decide to deploy the application on a new environment the application code should not change at all. Only external configuration may change.

So the solution that I've mentioned is better than what've you asked for, but still not ideal since it violates the environment-agnostic application way of creating the software.

Again, the best way is to think about environment as something static that exists and defines in startup which implementation is relevant.

Example, lets say in dev you use postgres, in production oracle (just for the sake of example).

So you can define something like this:

```
appliction-dev.properties 

db.oracle.enabled=false
db.postgres.enabled=true
db.postgres.user=...
db.postgres.password=...
--------------------------


application-prod.properties

db.oracle.enabled=true
db.postgres.enabled=false
db.oracle.user=...
db.oracle.password=...
```

Now lets pretend you have a data-source implementation one for oracle and one for Postgres (again, just an example, I know that spring in real life works differently)

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="db.oracle.enabled", havingValue = true)
public class OracleBaseConfiguration  {
      @Bean
      public DataSource dataSource () {
            //create oracle Datasource out of oracle configurations 
      }
}


@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="db.postgres.enabled", havingValue = true)
public class PostgresBaseConfiguration  {
      @Bean
      public DataSource dataSource () {
            //create postgres Datasource out of oracle configurations 
      }
}
```

If you absolutely have no choice, then there are two techniques in Spring that might be helpful:

I would recommend with an approach of creating a bean per environment and selecting a bean from some list / map in runtime.

**Technique 1:**
in case when environments are known in advance:

All beans might implement the same interface:

```
 interface EnvironmentAware {
    void doSomething();
    Environment getEnvironment();
 }


 class BeanForDev implements EnvironmentAware {
     public Environment getEnvironment() {
        return Environment.DEV;
     }
     public void doSomething() {...}
  }


  class BeanForProd implements EnvironmentAware {
     public Environment getEnvironment() {
        return Environment.PROD;
     }
     public void doSomething() {...}
  }

  public class MyService {
      private Map<Environment, EnvironmentAware> beans;

      public MyService(List<EnvironmentAware> beans) {
          // here is a trick - when you inject a list, spring will find all beans implementing the interface and inject them. So this is your autowired construction
        // so make it map and pick the bean from the map in runtime
      }
```

**Technique 2**

When environments are now known in advance but defined in configurations.
Again following the suggestion is to create a bean per environment

In spring its possible to create Beans dynamically (say per environment) with the help of `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. You can implement this interface and register dynamically created bean definitions. Its fairly advanced stuff so you should pretty much understand how does spring work in order to use this concepts, but technically it can help in dynamic creation of beans so I state this suggestion here as well.

Comment: To be precise, my requirement is a bit complex, I need to authenticate a user based on an ID that he gives in the request. If authenticated successfully, I need to create a rest template to hit his preferred service, this is again from the request to controller. The complexity lies in the authentication, coz user can give any ID and environment of his choice for authentication.

Comment: Well, consider treating the environment as something that comes from configurations in this case, as I see it the goal is to develop a software that won't change at the level of source code if you change the environment. Is it achievable?

Comment: Hmm I understand it cannot be. But this is one such scenario that goes against a software probably.

Comment: :) I've updated the answer with a couple of spring techniques that can be handy if you absolutely need this... Both of them can be used only if its really impossible to achieve environment agnostic code-base of your application IMO